# MS Access Delete Query with Left Join

Tags: ms-access, sql-delete

I am trying to run a delete query for all records in table 'CSD' that are not available in table 'Client Codes for dealing'. I am getting an error 'Could not delete from specified tables'

```
DELETE CSD.*
FROM CSD LEFT JOIN [Client Codes for dealing] ON CSD.CLIENT = [Client Codes for     dealing].ClientCode
WHERE ((([Client Codes for dealing].ClientCode) Is Null));
```

Comment: Doesn't the table have dependencies?

Comment: If you meant relationships, then no. Slight correction however to my previous post - the 'Client Codes for dealing' is a union query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your comment you mentioned that `[Client Codes for dealing]` is a Union query.  Anytime a UNION query is involved, the entire query is made read-only (see [Why is my query read-only?](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html)).

The simplest thing to do is to turn your UNION query into a make-table query, then replace the name of the UNION query with the name of the temporary local table created by the make-table query.